# The requested URL / was not found on this server. I used polymer-3-starter-kit

Tags: google-app-engine, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I followed these steps

```
mkdir my-app
cd my-app
polymer init polymer-3-starter-kit
```

and upload the project on the google app engine. I got this issue.

```
**Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.**
```

Comment: Could you add your question? If the question is related to app engine, we should add the tag, too.

Comment: Could you please share more information on how you upload your application up to Google App Engine? Giving further details or reproduction steps could be helpful to other members from the community, not only to understand your question, but also it is great to be able to have as much information as possible to debug your issue. Please bear in mind not to share any sensitive information (that being things like PROJECT_ID...). I hope it helps.